# tikzmark package no longer working?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzmark

It would seem that the tikzmark package is no longer working. When referring to marked points the point will be placed where it is called instead of the point that is marked. Eg. the basic example from the manual

```
\[
\tikzmark{a} e^{i\pi/2} = i
\]
This \tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=0pt] \draw[->] (0,1em) to [bend left] ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}] pic cs: a); is an important equation.
```

produces [image: current rendering of the above code]

rather than the intended [image: example image from tikzmark manual] (excuse the poor resolution).

I have tested this with both beamer and article in my MikTeX system, but it reproduces also on Overleaf, the online LaTeX compilation system (www.overleaf.com).

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you compile twice?

Comment: My apologizes! But thank you for the very swift reply. That did indeed fix the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is still working fine, but you had a space after the colon in `pic cs: a`. Get rid of this and the white space between `This \tikz[...` which introduces unneeded space here and you are ready to go.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmark{a} e^{i\pi/2} = i
\]
This\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw[->] (0,1em) to [bend left] ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}] pic cs:a); is an important equation.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you really want to show, what you are showing right now, you should of course prefer to do:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eipizwei}
e^{i\pi/2} = i
\end{equation}
Equation~\ref{eq:eipizwei} is an important one.
\end{document}
```